# Commands for window management on elementaryOS (or ubuntu-based systems in general)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-management

Currently, I'm using elementary OS, which is a fine distro with a great UI, but previous to this I have been using i3 (on Arch and Ubuntu) and I really miss the window management aspect using simple keybindings. I have been looking around for a while on how to manipulate the location and size of active (and maybe in extension inactive windows). I know that I can create custom keyboard shortcuts and all in the system settings, but the problem is that I don't know the exact command to make the windows behave the way I want after pressing the desired keybinding.

Specifically, there are two scenarios I want to adress: The first is that I want to have a vertical split between two windows, the left one (width=4/7) and the right one (width=3/7), kind of similar to the dwm layout.

```
----------------
|1      |2     |
|       |      |  
|       |      |
|       |      |
----------------
```

The second is that I want a 3 window slip. So the first window is on the left-hand side and has a width equal to half the monitor size and the second and third windows are on the right-hand side and are split horizontally, similar to any tiling window manager.

```
---------------
|1     |2     |
|      |      |
|      |------|
|      |3     |
|      |      |
---------------
```

Another (possible) binding I want to have, is the option to switch the position of the active window with the master window (window 1).

I know that I could just go back to i3 or dwm to have these binding, but I really want to make this work in my current UI.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish this and if it's even possible, but the simple answer is: Pantheon is not a tiling WM and isn't supposed to be. Maybe PopOS with it's new Tiling extension is what you're really looking for?

Comment: Expansion: The only tiling I'm aware of is Ctrl + Meta + Left/Right, which kind of accomplishes one of the things you want.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. Yes! This is kind of what I want, but I still want to manipulate the extent of the window management myself. I thought, since elementary is open source, somebody would know the commands (or how to find them) that define the window behaviour after pressing for example "Ctrl + Meta + Left/Right". And then I would be able to tinker a little bit to match it my needs.

Since I'm a mere coding beginner, I'm not sure I could find the part about window behaviour in pantheon.

Comment: I assume tiling behaviour is handled by Gala. You could install dconf-editor and check gala's (and maybe mutter) settings. But if it's not supported, it's not supported.